# It depends on how much money "I've got/ will have/ have"?

Tags: tense

I was paging through my grammar book and I came across with this sentence:

> I was thinking of going to china next year, but it depends on how much money **I've got**.

I  know ,here, **past progressive** refers to the future, but I cant figure out why present perfect tense has been used at the end? Does it have a subjunctive mode?

In addition, compare:

1. I was thinking of going to china next year, but it depends on how much money **I will have**.
2. I was thinking of going to china next year, but it depends on how much money **I have**.

In sentence **#2**, I used the bare infinitive *have* to imply subjunctive mood as matter of the fact that sentences similar to the highlighted one are extensively used in my native language (Persian) with subjunctive tone of voice.

Would you please help me to understand the difference(s) between these three sentences?

Comment: I am not sure **I've got** means *I've got until now* or *I've got until then (since then)*

Comment: Analogy: As soon as I've got/earned money enough for a trip to China, I'll go there.

Comment: See also http://ell.stackexchange.com/search?q=I%27ve+got+have+

Comment: @AlanCarmack How many post should I read? There are so many have/have got questions ?

Comment: @AlanCarmack And also, my question was not completely about have got vs have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I was thinking of going to China next year, but it depends on how much money I've got.

This is a very interesting sentence; there's a lot more going on here than you may suspect.

1. In the first place, there's no question of a "subjunctive" here. This is immediately apparent if you transpose these verbs into 3d person singular, which is the only situation in which a "subjunctive" use of *have* would be discernible:

   > ...how much money he's got, *not* he'*ve got
   >   ...how much money he has, *not* he *have
2. The past progressive *I was thinking* does **not** refer to the future: the trip under consideration lies in the future, but the act of considering it does not.

   The past tense here may have either "actual" or "virtual" past reference—that is, it may refer to an actual past occasion on which you considered this trip ("I was thinking about it yesterday"), but it is more likely to mean that you're still considering it, but only tentatively. This very common tentative use of the past progressive suggests that you have in a sense suspended your consideration of the trip, because you've recognized a factor that prevents you from pressing on to a definite decision.
3. *Have got* isn't necessarily a present perfect; how you parse it depends in large part on your dialect.

   - In American Englishes, *have got* is almost never a perfect: here the past participle of *get* is *gotten*, and *have got* is an idiom equivalent to *have*. It is employed only in the present tense. For a US speaker *how much money I**'ve got*** is a present-tense construction and is indistinguishable from *how much money I **have***.
   - Anglo Englishes employ the same idiom (it's actually very old, going back to the period before the two dialects went their separate ways), but because in Anglo Englishes *got* **is** the past participle of *get*, the expression is ambiguous between present and present perfect.

     Consequently, Anglo speakers are far more likely to use *have got* in  negatives and interrogatives, deploying *have* as an ordinary auxiliary: Anglo speakers tend to deploy *have* as an auxiliary (*I haven't got enough money*, *Have you got enough money?*) where US speakers usually abandon the *have got* idiom and use bare *have* with *do* support (*I don't have enough money*, *Do you have enough money?*).<sup>†</sup>

     In fact, there is a growing tendency among US speakers to drop the *have* piece of *have got* entirely, employing *got* as a present-tense verb distinct from *get*. Consider, for instance, Gershwin's famous song:

     > I got rhythm
     >   I got music
     >   I got my girl,
     >   Who could ask for anything more?

     And in some US speech communities this *got* may now be employed by itself with *do* support in negatives and interrogatives:

     > If you got it, flaunt it, if you don't got it, flaunt it. —Mindy Kaling
     >   What do you got, if you ain't got love —Bon Jovi
4. Supposing that you **can** distinguish present and present perfect in this context, there is a difference. Both are present tenses, and because *have* is stative both designate a state of possessing money at the time you're talking about; the difference lies in whether or not you allude to the process of obtaining it. Let's use the very distinct US forms:

   > I have got money = "I possess money"—*there's no allusion to when or you obtained it*.
   >   I have gotten money = "I have obtained money"—*you possess money which at some prior point you did not have*.
5. *I have*, *I have got* and *I have gotten* are all present-tense constructions. BUT ... In this context none of them necessarily has present-tense reference: any of them may refer to a future state rather than a present one. The ambiguity can be resolved by context; for instance, with a specific temporal locative:

   > It depends on how much money I{'ve got/'ve gotten/ have} **next year**. We'll have to see.
   >   It depends on how much money I{'ve got/'ve gotten/ have} **now**. I'm about to check my bank account.

   Futurives with *will* are not ordinarily used in this sort of closely integrated subordinate clause; your final example will not be misunderstood, but it falls very strangely on the ear:

   > It depends on how much money I <sup>?</sup>will have.

   This is a very tricky area of usage, however: this sort of futurive *will* is acceptable in some contexts or with some speakers, and I haven't seen a definitive analysis of what sorts of subordinate clauses do and do not permit it. In any case, volitive *will* is acceptable: *It depends on whether John will lend me the money*, which means "whether John proves willing to lend me the money".)

---

<sup>†</sup> In some speech communities, however, the deprecated *ain't* for *haven't* is common: *I ain't got enough money*.

Comment: Many Thanks, I think I should peruse this answer multiple times for some days. I am speechless dear StoneyB.

Answer (score 1):

Like lexical **have**, auxiliary **have** can be projected into the future.

```
  Will Team X win the Cup? 
    --Maybe.   It will depend on how many good players ...
        a) they have next year.
        b) they've managed to acquire by next year.
```

Comment: Thanks, I think I must find a way to get rid of my native language interference. I am obsessed with subjunctives.

Comment: We have few true subjunctive verb forms left, and even some of the ones that remain frozen-in-amber are sometimes recategorized as "prepositions".  For example, "You'll rue that decision, *come* tomorrow."

Comment: @Cardinal we (Persian) use both subjunctive and future verb not? .. بستگی داره چقدر پول داشته باشم .and...بستگی داره چقدر پول خواهم داشت... if we want to mention the future time we even can use present (however a bit odd)... بستگی داره چقدر پول سال آینده دارم...

Comment: is using **next year** obligatory to resolve the ambiguity?  because otherwise how you would say *...how many good players they have right now...*

Comment: @Ahmad Bull eyes, exactly, we do use both. But, I personally always use subjunctives. My another big problem is, English speakers use present simple tense ----- Instead of "It depends on how much money he have" they say "It depends on how much money he has/has got/...". That really makes trouble for me.

Comment: No, "next year" is not necessary.  "Will you take a vacation next year? --Maybe. It depends on how busy we *are*."

Answer (score 0):

The expression [I've got](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/quick-grammar/british-english-and-american-english) is typically British English:

> I was thinking of going to china next year, but it depends on how much money **I've got**

Whereas an American English speaker would say:

> I was thinking of going to china next year, but it depends on how much money **I have**.

This is the same as your sentence #2. Note that **have** is not a bare infinitive: it is present simple. You can put it into the third person like this:

> John was thinking of going to china next year, but it depends on how much money he **has**.

Referring to sentence #1: When we use a conditional, like **it depends on**, we can use the present simple to imply a future state- in other words, it's ok to say **I have** rather than **I will have**. The listener will assume that the speaker is talking about how much money he will have at the time the condition is applied (next year, in this case).

Here is another example of using **I have** rather than **I will have** with a conditional:

> I will help you tomorrow, if **I have** time.

Comment: Is it right to say: "John was thinking of going to china next year, but it depends on how much money he have.", I mean subjunctive mood. I am obsessed with subjunctives in my native language :(

Comment: *'ve got* is only somewhat less common in US speech than BrE, but 1) it is somewhat deprecated in US formal use, and tends to be less used by women 2) it is very rarely used in negatives and interrogatives 3) as I point out in my answer, it is tending more and more to lose the *'ve* element.

Comment: @Cardinal: no, it is not OK to use **have**. The subjunctive is used in only limited circumstances in  English: see this link. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_subjunctive